# default installation directory as an argument for python-2.7.x.msi

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, windows-installer

I am trying to install Python-2.7 from my application by running the python-2.7.x.msi from the command line. I want to know whether the default installation path (which is "C:/Python27" by default) can be changed to some other path. Will I be able to do this by passing any arguments while running the installer MSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Using Windows Installer - Non-interactive installation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/):

> With the command line
>
> ```
> msiexec /i python<version>.msi
> ```
>
> installation can be initiated programmatically. Additional parameters
>   can be passed at the end of this command line, like
>
> ```
> msiexec /i python-2.5.msi TARGETDIR=r:\python25
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Target directory**
>
> The property `TARGETDIR` determines the root directory of the Python
>   installation. For example, a different installation drive can be
>   specified with
>
> ```
> TARGETDIR=R:\python25
> ```
>
> The default `TARGETDIR` is `[WindowsVolume]Python<version>`.

So you can do like:

```
msiexec /i python-2.7.x.msi TARGETDIR=c:\other\place\to\install
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. How can I specify a path relative to the windows volume? Currently, I'm hardcoding it (C:\myfolder).